# How to use Xamarin Android LocationManager.GetCurrentLocation?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

How can you use `LocationManager.GetCurrentLocation` with Xamarin.Android?

Specifically, I can't figure out how to use the IConsumer parameter required.

**Here's the documentation for it:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.locations.locationmanager.getcurrentlocation?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12

**EDIT**:

If I leave my test device (Android 6) on my desk, next to a window, it'll only ever return null locations until I walk around with the device. Network reception is good, and if I return to the exact same location once it's "woken up" then GPS signal is good. This is true even for the lowest accuracy request.

Here's an example of the code I'm using (have tried various timeouts, and polling continuously):

Here's the code I'm using:

```
        // Get the last known location, from the OS cache
        Location cached = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();

        // Location found?
        if (cached != null)
            OnLocationFound(cached);

        // Get current location
        GeolocationRequest networkRequest = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Lowest, timeout);
        Location network = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(networkRequest, cancellationToken.Token);

        // Location found?
        if (network != null)
            OnLocationFound(network);

        // Get current location
        GeolocationRequest gpsRequest = new GeolocationRequest(GeolocationAccuracy.Medium, timeout);
        Location gps = await Geolocation.GetLocationAsync(gpsRequest, cancellationToken.Token);

        // Location found?
        if (gps != null)
            OnLocationFound(gps);
```

Comment: is there a reason you need to use that specific API, as opposed to the method documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/location

Comment: @Jason so that we're not dependant on Google Play Services.

Comment: @Jason Also, I can't seem to get the FusedLocationUpdates working anyway (Android 6).

Comment: Hi @Le-royStaines, can you explain how your code doesn't work? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I think there's a deeper issue. I've managed to get Xamarin Essentials to return a location, but if the device doesn't move then eventually it stops waking up the GPS receiver and returns a null location. Almost like Android doesn't bother, because it thinks the device hasn't moved, and yet it's cleared the cached entries too. 

FusedLocationUpdates returns null.

Comment: Have you tested on other devices?  If it is convenient for you, could you please post  a basic demo so that we can test on our side?

Comment: @Jessie I have on others of the same model, but not on others with a different model. Namely because the device in question that I need to support is an older version of Android (6). I'm fairly confident however that it's a combination of the underlying ActivityManager and a maximum age on the cache. The activity manager seems to be preventing the location receiver/s from waking up as it's detected no movement, but then the cache empties at some point and lastKnownLocation returns null as well.